# Had seen an ad for a thumb drive like ATA device that has a RJ11 on the output and RJ45 on the input - what was it?

Tags: voip, magicjack

I seem to recall an ad for a thumb drive like ATA device that had a RJ11 jack that you could plug your DSL line to ( or maybe it was an Ethernet port) and on the other side you could hook up a cordless or something.

The same company was offering phone service for $19.95 or something.

I am pretty sure it was not MagicJack, as I remember telling myself "well, this one does not need a computer".

Have you guys seen the ad/recall what this hardware device was?

It seemed pretty self contained ( probably draws power over Ethernet or the phone line ) - and was much smaller than the MJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been [nettalk-duo](http://www.laptopmag.com/review/voip/nettalk-duo.aspx#axzz14lBNJVZt). In that case the price would be 29.95 instead of what I recall. There are so many new devices like these - it's hard to be sure what I saw - hence I will keep this open in the hope for for better suggestions